# AsyncTask, how to properly use WeakReference in all the UI methods

Tags: android, android-asynctask, weak-references

I want to use the `WeakReference` approach to not leak memory with my `AsyncTask`. I found examples online and on Stackoverflow, but they only get the reference in `onPostExecute` and I am unsure how to correctly use it in all 3 of the UI methods.
My current approach is like this, but I have no clue if I can get rid of some redundancy. Why can't I just call `activityReference.get()` in the constructor and then only check for null in each of the UI methods? Why do the examples online call `get` right before using the `WeakReference`?

```
private static class ExampleAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, String> {
    private WeakReference<MainActivity> activityReference;

    ExampleAsyncTask(MainActivity context) {
        activityReference = new WeakReference<>(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        MainActivity activity = activityReference.get();
        if (activity == null || activity.isFinishing()) {
            return;
        }

        activity.progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Integer... integers) {
        for (int i = 1; i < integers[0]; i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            publishProgress((i * 100) / integers[0]);
        }

        return "Finished";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);

        MainActivity activity = activityReference.get();
        if (activity == null || activity.isFinishing()) {
            return;
        }

        activity.progressBar.setProgress(values[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        MainActivity activity = activityReference.get();
        if (activity == null || activity.isFinishing()) {
            return;
        }

        activity.progressBar.setProgress(0);
        activity.progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Toast.makeText(activity, s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can initialise it in the constructor and use it in all methods.

```
private static class ExampleAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, String>
{
    private WeakReference<MainActivity> activityReference;
    MainActivity activity;

    ExampleAsyncTask(MainActivity context)
    {
        activityReference = new WeakReference<>(context);
        activity = activityReference.get();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();

        if (activity == null || activity.isFinishing())
        {
            return;
        }

        activity.progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Integer... integers)
    {
        if (activity == null)
            return null;

        for (int i = 1; i < integers[0]; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            publishProgress((i * 100) / integers[0]);
        }

        return "Finished";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values)
    {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);

        if (activity == null || activity.isFinishing())
        {
            return;
        }

        activity.progressBar.setProgress(values[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        if (activity == null || activity.isFinishing())
        {
            return;
        }

        activity.progressBar.setProgress(0);
        activity.progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Toast.makeText(activity, s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this makes more sense to me!

Comment: Well I was hoping to get a 2nd opinion on this to be sure

Comment: Actually I think `get` returns a strong reference to the activity, which would destroy the purpose of the WeakReference if I keep it as a member. Don't you think so?

Comment: NO way. It only holds reference (not implicit/strong reference), whenever the `Activity` is destroyed, it will become null. That's the whole point of using `WeakReference`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166617/discussion-between-copsonroad-and-florian-walther).

Comment: @CopsOnRoad does it really make sense if you get strong reference in constructor? Isn't better to call `get` on-demand and check for null?

Comment: @CAMOBAP Yes, you can do that way also, but only downside is you have to use this many times which is why I decided to put in constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The most correct and obvious way to use weak reference here is not to. Instead, you should cancel the task when Activity gets destroyed. This will prevent memory leak and stop async computation which became useless.

```
public final class SomeActivity extends Activity {
    private AsyncTask<?, ?, ?> runningTask;
    private void startTaskPlease() {
        if (runningTask != null) runningTask.cancel(true);
        runningTask = new ExampleAsyncTask(this);
        runningTask.execute();
    }
    @Override protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (runningTask != null) runningTask.cancel(true);
    }
}
```

Now your `AsyncTask#doInBackground` should be interruption-friendly, but UI part should not mind weak references and cancellation.

```
public final class ExampleAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<whatever> {
    private final SomeActivity activity; // now this is OK! Thanks to cancellation
    public ExampleAsyncTask(SomeActivity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }
}
```